# Handlebars template not being rendered in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, web, handlebars.js

This is my `index.js` code which is supposed to render `index.hbs` inside `views` directory but gives error `Error: ENOENT no such file or directory, open '__dirname\views\layouts\main.hbs'` , i dont even have a layouts folder.

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', expressHbs({extname: 'hbs'}));
app.set('views', 'views');

app.get('/', (req,res)=> {
   res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log("SERVER HAS STARTED ON PORT 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a layouts folder for express-handlebars to find your index.hbs.  By default handlebars looks for main.hbs first then the index.hbs to be rendered in in main.hbs.

[image: file str]

Just for clarification in app.engine my extname is set to "html".  Hope this helps.
You can read up on it at [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)